# How to use $elemMatch in kinvey-flex-sdk?

Tags: mongodb, kinvey

Is there any way, how to use **$elemMatch Projection Operators** in kinvey-flex-sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
var dataStore = modules.dataStore({ skipBl: true, useMasterSecret: true });
var collection = dataStore.collection('<collectionName>');
var query = new Kinvey.Query();
query.equalTo('items', { $elemMatch: { item: 'a', qty: { $gte: 23 } } });

collection.find(query, function (error, result) {

});
```